# Difference between bind and provide in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm busy learning Angular2 and I wonder what the difference is between `bind()` and `provide()`. In my application I can't seem to find any differences, so I wonder what the differences are to make a better decision on which one to use. At the moment I'm using the latest version of ***Angular2: beta17***.

Example **bind**:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router'
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/platform/common';
import { bind } from 'angular2/core';

// Main Component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy)
]);
```

Example **provide**:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router'
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/platform/common';
import { provide } from 'angular2/core';

// Main Component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Günter said, `bind` is deprecated unlike `provide`.

The `provide` function is just a wrapper that calls the constructor of the `Provider` class:

```
provide(token, { ... });
```

is the same than:

```
new Provider(token, { ... });
```

`bind` leverages the `ProviderBuilder` helper class to build a provider. Whereas `bind` is deprecated, the `ProviderBuilder` isn't and can be used this way:

```
ProviderBuilder pb = new ProviderBuilder();
pb.toClass(type);
pb.toValue(value);
pb.toFactory(factory);
```

is the same than:

```
new Provider(token, { useClass: ... });
new Provider(token, { useValue: ... });
new Provider(token, { useFactory: ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

`bind` is just the deprecated predecessor of `provide` and does exactly the same.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/core/src/di/provider.ts#L254